# Should parameter assertion in Javascript throw directly when function returns Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, promise, assertion

I have been writing NodeJS code for quite some time now, and seen different techniques implemented by people. My question is weather it is considered best practice having a function that as a signature returns a `Promise`, throw directly when parameter assertion fails.

So you think we should do this? :

**Throw sync way**

```
function asyncPromise(param) {
    assert(param, 'Missing required parameter');
    // Param ok
    return Promise.resolve(param);
}
```

OR this ? :

**Rejected Promise**

```
function rejectPromise(param) {
    if (typeof param === 'undefined') {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Missing required parameter'));
    }
    // Param valid
    return Promise.resolve(value);
}
```

My gut is telling me to go for the first way of directly throwing since wrong parameter input should be considered as something that should not continue, however when a function has a signature of returning a Promise, the caller expects a .catch handling of an error, and will miss the error if thrown directly.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Asking for opinion is outside the scope of this site https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'd use `throw`, but inside the executor. This is the same as `.reject` but more explicit.

Comment: @Purefan Maybe asking for opinion was not the proper definition... Probably you could say I am asking what is considered best practice, (if any)

Comment: If you do it the first way, surely any calling code needs to handle the fact that there is no `then()` to chain to. ie, you just lost the ability to do `somethingElse.then(x => asyncPromise(x).then(...))`

Comment: Useful article for Error handling info in NodeJS https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you ask about asynchronous promises but use synchronous code example.

Correct relevant code should look something like this:

```
/**
 * @return Promise Resolved when a value is accepted, rejected otherwise.
 * @throw  AssertionException When no parameter is given.
 */
function asyncPromise(param) {
    assert(param, 'Missing required parameter');

    var promise = new Promise(param);
    something.process(promise); //start asynchronous process

    return Promise;
}

//somewhere else while processing
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (Exception err) {
    promise.reject(err);
}

//somewhere else after processing is done
if (success) {
    promise.resolve(result);
}
else {
    promise.reject(error);
}
```

In this code there are two places where an error can happen: A) in the `asyncPromise()` which is synchronous error and can be safely handled by throwing an Exception and B) the processing where throwing an Exception would stop the processing but would not return any reply into the original function rendering the code *frozen*. In such case you **must** reject the promise instead of throwing an exception.

Solving the case A) by either rejecting the promise or throwing an exception should depend on what is the cause of the problem: If due to the problem you cannot create or process the promise (or something related to it) then it should return an exception. If on other hand you can safely create the promise but a problem arise while you try to start the processing, then it should reject the promise. Also good reason to reject the promise is when you realize there is no reason to start the process (e.g. when you already tried and failed).

---

Also **note that the function clearly states that it returns a Promise but can throw an Exception** if the parameter is not defined. That way **everyone knows what to expect** and how to use it.